# Spring Lazy Init = true in dependent jars

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I have an application which has a number of dependent jar files. Each of these have a spring.xml. How can set lazy init = true for beans defined  within these jar files?

Some of the spring.xml files in the dependent jar files have lazy init = false explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding custom [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) like so:

```
@Configuration
class BeanLifecycleConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor changeCustomComponentsToLazyInit() {
        return new BeanFactoryPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
                for (String name : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
                    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(name);
                    if (beanDefinition.getBeanClassName().startsWith("your.package.name")) {
                        beanDefinition.setLazyInit(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```